# Clojure map destructuring in functions that require a single key

Tags: clojure

I've currently implemented a way to sort by a deep key in a map like so:

```
(sort-by #(get-in % [:layer :order]) [{:layer {:order 1} {:layer {:order 2}])
```

I was wondering if there was a way to do this using map destructuring? Is that available for functions outside of `let` and parameter definition? An example of what I'm wondering is possible:

```
(sort-by {:layer {:order}} [{:layer {:order 1} {:layer {:order 2}])
```

Comment: More of the sort-by source would be helpful. The short answer is **yes**, destructing works on function arguments as well.

Comment: @FrankC. The [sort-by](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/sort-by) function is the one from the clojure.core lib.

Comment: Ahh, mea culpa. @birdspider has your direct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so because sort-by needs a value extraction function (keyfn)

*(that is unless you want to sort entries directly by themself)*

```
user=> (doc sort-by)
-------------------------
clojure.core/sort-by
([keyfn coll] [keyfn comp coll])
 Returns a sorted sequence of the items in coll, where the sort
 order is determined by comparing (keyfn item).  If no comparator is
 supplied, uses compare.  comparator must implement
 java.util.Comparator.  If coll is a Java array, it will be modified.
 To avoid this, sort a copy of the array.
```

EDIT: what you can do is "simulate" `get-in` via compose and keyword lookups as in

`(sort-by (comp :a :c) [ {:c {:a 3}} {:c {:a 2}} ])`

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, you can only destructure within a let binding or function binding. This is how you might do it with nested map destructuring:

```
(sort-by (fn [{{o :order} :layer}] o)
         [{:layer {:order 2}}
          {:layer {:order 1}}])
```

I don't think that's any clearer, though. Since keywords are functions, you could also use plain old function composition:

```
(sort-by (comp :order :layer)
         [{:layer {:order 2}}
          {:layer {:order 1}}])
```